# Fetch request canceled when sending image file to Flask server

Tags: javascript, json, flask, cors, fetch-api

I'm building a web application that performs OCR (Optical Character Recognition) on uploaded images using JavaScript (Fetch API) on the frontend and Flask on the backend. The application allows users to upload an image, and upon clicking the "Convert" button, the image is sent to the Flask server for processing.
The frontend is written in HTML and JavaScript.
The backend is built with Flask, and I've set up CORS to allow requests from my localhost.
I'm using the Fetch API to send the image file to the server.
The Flask route /process_image handles the image processing and returns the extracted text as JSON.
**Code:**
The **frontend** is:

```
const convertButtonEl = document.getElementById("convert-button");
convertButtonEl.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const imageFile = document.getElementById("file-upload").files[0];
    if (imageFile) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", imageFile);
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/process_image", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.extracted_text) {
                document.getElementById("text-display").textContent = data.extracted_text;
            } else {
                console.error("Error:", data.error);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Fetch error:", error);
        });
    }
});
```

The **backend** is:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pytesseract
import cv2
from flask_cors import CORS  

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/process_image", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def process_image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        uploaded_image = request.files['image']
        extracted_text = perform_ocr(uploaded_image)
        return jsonify({"extracted_text": extracted_text})
    
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "Method not allowed"})
    
def perform_ocr(uploaded_image):
    image_path = f"uploads/{uploaded_image.filename}" 
    uploaded_image.save(image_path)
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    text=pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The relevant **HTML** is

```
  <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">Upload Image</label>
    <input type="file" id="file-upload" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
    
    <!-- Button to trigger text extraction -->
    <button id="convert-button" type="submit">Convert image to text</button>
    
    <!-- Area to display extracted text -->
    <div id="text-display"></div>
```

**Troubleshooting:**

I've verified that the event listener is properly bound to the button.
I've tried different ports for the Flask server.
The network request appears as "canceled" in the browser's network tab.
There are no console errors or warnings in the browser's console.

When I click the "Convert" button, the Fetch request to the Flask server is being canceled, and I can't figure out why. The network tab briefly shows the request as "canceled" with a "fetch" type. I've gone through various debugging steps and tried different approaches, but I'm still facing this issue.
I'm stuck on why the Fetch request is being canceled. Is there anything specific I'm missing or any steps I can take to troubleshoot further?